# nginx, Magento & Cloudfront

Tags: magento, nginx, amazon-cloudfront

I have inherited a website that is running Magento & nginx.  I know virtually nothing about nginx and know a fair amount about Magento.  The site is configured to use the Amazon Cloudfront CDN however all of the images, js & css are returning a 301 redirect to the origin site.  I have a development site running Apache with the same Magento, MySQL & Cloudfront setup that is functioning correctly with this setup so I am pretty sure it is a problem with the config file for nginx.  There have been some rewrites written in to the file and my assumption is that when the request for an asset at skin.mydomain.com is made it is redirecting to www.mydomain.com instead of serving the file from the CDN.  I have CNAME records setup for js.mydomain.com, skin.mydomain.com and cloud.mydomain.com that all point to the same Cloudfront CDN.  Here is the portion of the nginx config file that would seem to be applicable:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   ##127.0.0.1:8080
   server_name mydomain.com;
   rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
    listen 80;
    ##127.0.0.1:8080 default
        ## SSL directives might go here
        listen 443 default ssl;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/

    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    ## *.mydomain.com; Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/magento;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
        expires 30d;
        if ($request_uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$") {
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
        port_in_redirect off;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have been working on this pretty much all day and would like to stop working on it at some point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears the first `server` directive is forcing a rewrite of the www.

```
server {
 . . .
    rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
 . . . 
}
```